# Remove duplicate values in pandas but after some manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataset as such

```
{col_A  col_B   col_Z
Sam      time1    time2
Sam      time3  time4
R        time1  time2
H        time1  time2
H        time5  time6}
```

I want to have output as such

```
{col_A  col_B   col_Z
Sam      time1  time4
R        time1  time2
H        time1  time6}
```

I tried using drop duplicates but no use so far. Basic assumptions is that time1 < time3 and time2 < time4, same for user **H** as well but we don't need to do the comparison for the col_B and col_Z.

Comment: Could you please post the current code you have?

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(['col_A'],keep= 'last')`
This completly removes the first row, however, i want to keep col_B of first row and col_Z of 2nd one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have two approaches to this problem:**

The first involves simple looping where I get the `time` value in `col_B` and the `time` value in `col_Z`:

```py
# Import packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Set up variables for new columns
names = np.unique(df['col_A'])
firstTimes = []
lastTimes = []

# Loop through name? in col_A of df
for name in names:
    nameData = df.loc[df['col_A'] == name]
    firstTime = nameData.to_numpy()[0,1]
    lastTime = nameData.to_numpy()[-1,2]
    
    firstTimes.append(firstTime)
    lastTimes.append(lastTime)

# Create the dataframe
dNew = {'col_A': names, 'col_B': firstTimes, 'col_Z': lastTimes}
filteredDF = pd.DataFrame(data = dNew)
```

where `df` is your example Pandas DataFrame and `filteredDF` the new filtered DataFrame (as shown below):

```
    col_A   col_B   col_Z
0   H       time1   time6
1   R       time1   time2
2   Sam     time1   time4
```

The second is assuming the values in `col_B` and `col_Z` are `Datetime` or `Timestamp` values. I utilize Pandas' `groupby()` function to group each of the values in `col_A`, then aggregate its values for `col_B` as a min and `col_Z` as a max:

```py
dfNew = df.groupby('col_A').agg({'col_B':'min', 'col_Z':'max'}).reset_index()
```

For example, if `df` looks like this:

```
    col_A    col_B                  col_Z
0   Sam      1970-01-01 00:00:10    1970-01-01 00:00:20
1   Sam      1970-01-01 00:00:30    1970-01-01 00:00:40
2   R        1970-01-01 00:00:10    1970-01-01 00:00:20
3   H        1970-01-01 00:00:10    1970-01-01 00:00:20
4   H        1970-01-01 00:00:50    1970-01-01 00:01:00
```

then `dfNew` will look like this (NOTE: `col_A` is sorted alphabetically):

```
    col_A   col_B                   col_Z
0   H       1970-01-01 00:00:10     1970-01-01 00:01:00
1   R       1970-01-01 00:00:10     1970-01-01 00:00:20
2   Sam     1970-01-01 00:00:10     1970-01-01 00:00:40
```

**Clearly, as you can see, method 2 is much more simple if you are working with the appropriate datatypes that can be aggregated!**

Comment: The second method worked great for me. I had other columns as well, that didn't needed to be same, so, i kept them in the groupby part.
Thanks for the help. You saved me countless hours.

Comment: @TechKnow Glad I could help!